# Clustering with a constraint on the size of clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, algorithms

Assuming a set of customer location coordinates, and ***n*** truck drivers (each driver's truck can carry p number of items).

Because each truck can carry a different amount of items, is there a way to perform n clusters such that each cluster only contains p number of customers. (We can assume that each customer orders one item)

More generally, assuming a dataset containing *xy* coordinates, what is the best way to output k clusters such that the number of elements in each cluster is set as an input to the function.

I was thinking that there may be some way of modifying the k means clustering algorithm in some way, but I am not sure how I would go about that. Are there any more efficient alternatives?

Comment: Lots of results for k-means constrained to come up with similar cluster sizes comes up when googling.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have found resources that explain "similar" cluster sizes. But I could not find anything that explains how to have clusters with predefined different number of elements.

Comment: I think your problem is not really a ML problem but rather an optimization / allocation problem. Given N elements, categorize into k groups according to a certains criteria and knowing each group has size $n_1,n_2,n_3,...,n_k$. 
Your problem might even be more precise because it is about splitting the plane xy into k groups with $n_k$ elements in each group. 
Have you try searching in that direction ?

Comment: Also you can try to look into hierarchical clustering because it is much easier to stop the algorithm at a desire cluster size. You can even plot the tree that the algorithm use to build the clusters